# Different results invoking bash directly or via soft link

Tags: bash

On my Red Hat Linux system `/bin/sh` is a link to `bash`

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Sep 27 13:17 /bin/sh -> bash
```

Running this contrived test program directly gives me the expected answer

```
$ cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/sh
# Just a test program to illustrate an issue
case "b" in
    (a)   echo "a"; break;;
    (b)   echo "b"; break;;
    (c)   echo "c"; break;;
esac

$ ./test.sh 
b
```

But explicitly running it under `bash`, or changing the initial line to invoke `bash` gives an error. I understand that this may be a real `bash` error - but why the difference?

```
$ /bin/bash ./test.sh
b
./test.sh: line 5: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop

$ sed -e 's/sh/bash/' test.sh > test1.sh
$ chmod 777 test1.sh
$ ./test1.sh
b
./test1.sh: line 5: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `man` page for `bash`:

> If bash is invoked with the name **sh**, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of **sh** as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

However, saying that, the [POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#break) of `break` doesn't include it's use within a `case` block.

The `man` page also states (under the definition of the `case`):

> If the **;;** operator is used, no subsequent matches are attempted after the first pattern match

And [POSIX definition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) of `case` says:

> The conditional construct case shall execute the compound-list corresponding to the **first one** of several patterns

So the bottom line is - you don't need the `break` as the `case` stops after the first match.

Answer (score 1):

From the bash man page:

> If  bash  is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup
>   behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while
>   conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

In opposite to C/C++, you do not need `break` in a switch/case statement in shell scripting.